# Association Rules With a Particular Structure in Rapid Minner

Tags: regex, associations, data-mining, rapidminer

In Rapid Minner , I need to generate association rules with particular structure , such as :

```
[temp=cold, wind=slow] --> [rain=true]  
[temp=hot , wind=slow] --> [rain=false]  
[temp=cold, wind=fast] --> [rain=true]
```

That prediction of raining should be a part of the conclusion. I have studied Documentation of RapidMinner, it suggests to use Regular Expression in FP-Growth node (must contain a field). But it doesn't include any samples for using regular expression in association rules. I need a sample for using regular expressions (regex) in association rules.

Comment: Rapidminer *usage* questions are better asked in the official rapidminer forum. Unless you are writing actual *code*, that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i ask my question in Rapid Miner forum , and find some answers. you can see [here](http://rapid-i.com/rapidforum/index.php/topic,9071.msg30506.html#msg30506)